# Where To get Tbjeditablecolumn of bootstrap? where is the method 'registerPackage'?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I wanna do the editable grid, going thru this [tutorial](http://www.farifam.com/site/content/361-Allow+Edit+Data+On+Your+GridView+In+Yii+Framework.html#.UgzweZLJRyN).
yet, as i downloaded the `yiibooster-1.1.0` i found there **TbExtendedGridView**, yet no **TbJEditableColumn** file there.
Where to get it?

As i've added the following column in TbExtendedGridView widjet, i get the error: **In the class Bootstrap and its methods there is no method or ... 'registerPackage'**.

```
array(
            'name' => 'assortment_amount',
            'header' => 'Количество ред.',
            'class' => 'ext.bootstrap.widgets.TbEditableColumn',
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:90px'),
            'editable' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
            )
        ),
```

the same pops up when i add this (from [tutorial](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extended-grid.html#gridcolumns)):

```
array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'header' => 'Region Name',
        'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbEditableColumn',
        'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:80px'),
        'editable' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            )
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Usage](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extended-grid.html).

You can find it on Github
[Download](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBooster/tree/master/src/widgets)

[TbEditableColumn.php](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBooster/blob/master/src/widgets/TbEditableColumn.php)

Comment: Telvin, i followed your link, found nothing of **TbJEditableColumn**... :-(

Comment: I believe that was the typo in your tutorial.I just see the TbEditableColumn.php, not TbJEditableColumn what I've never seen ever. You could see on my reference Usage see official demo how it work

Comment: Telvin, i've done as you suggested, (though in the very 1st par. in here there is 'TbJEditableColumn - for inline editing'). But i get the error: **In the class Bootstrap and its methods there is no method or ... 'registerPackage'**.  В классе Bootstrap и его поведениях не найден метод или замыкание с именем "registerPackage".